# How to select (grep) many different patterns by bash via a pipe?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

**My task**
I have a file A.txt with the following content.

```
aijdish uhuih
buh iiu hhuih
zhuh hiu
d uhiuhg ui
...
```

I want to select lines with these words `aijdish`, `d`, `buh` ...
I only know that I can:

```
cat A.txt | grep "aijdish" > temp.txt
cat A.txt | grep "d" >> temp.txt
cat A.txt | grep "buh" >> temp.txt
...
```

**But** I have several thousands of words need to select this time, how can I do this under bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have many words you want to look for I suggest putting the pattern into a file and use greps `-f` option:

```
$ cat grep-pattern.txt
aijdish
buh
d

$ grep -f grep-pattern.txt inputfile
aijdish uhuih
buh iiu hhuih
d uhiuhg ui
```

But if you have words like *d* you might want to add the `-w` option to match only whole words and not parts of words.

```
grep -wf grep-pattern.txt inputfile
```

Comment: Given the presence of `d` in the patterns, it is probably a good idea to add `-w` to the invocation of grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -E "aijdish|d|buh" inputfile
aijdish uhuih
buh iiu hhuih
d uhiuhg ui
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not too applicable when I have several thousands of different words

Answer (score 0):

Store the words to be searched in a file (say a.txt) and then write a script for searching every line in a.txt and matching it in the required file

Comment: I know but I want to learn how to do it with bash only. Thank you